# I cannot delete a .dat file using file operations of Java

Tags: java, file, delete-file

I have tried a number of methods for deleting a .dat file using the file operations of Java but none seem to work for me. The methods that I have tried are all searched from StackOverflow. Below is my code:

```
public static void removeRecords(Scanner in, ArrayList<BankAccount> listOfAccounts) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Enter Administrator Password:");
    String password = in.next();

    if (password.equals("2022")) {
//      The file pathname should be edited according to the directory where the program files are placed
        File folder = new File("C:/Users/nilay/OneDrive/Desktop/Bank Account/");
        File fList [] = folder.listFiles();
//      Searching for accountList.dat and deleting the file
        boolean success = false;

        for (File file: fList) {
            if (file.getName().endsWith(" .dat")) {
                success = file.delete();
            }
        }
        if (success) {
            System.out.println("All account records have been successfully removed. Returning back to Main Menu.");
        } else if (!success) {
            System.out.println("File not deleted.");
        }
    }
```

I always get "File not deleted" as the output. Please help me.

Comment: Seems to be a space before ".dat" in your comparison?

Comment: Could also be from case sensitivity.

Comment: A better solution than just matching the name is to use a `PathMatcher`. Something like `getPathMatcher("glob:*.dat").matches(file.toPath())`

Comment: sprinter could you please elaborate on how I could use the PathMatcher? I don't clearly understand.

Answer (score 2):

`File.delete()` will return true only if it deletes the file. Meaning it will return false if the file does not exist. Ensure `File.exists()` returns true prior to invoking `File.delete()`:

```
if (file.exists()) {
    if (file.delete()) {
    } else {
    }
}
```

Also see `Files.deleteIfExists()` which may provide more information, via an IOException, in the event of a failed deletion attempt:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

try {
    final Path p = Paths.get(searchCust + " booking.dat");
    if (Files.deleteIfExists(p)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deleted " + p);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p + " does not exist.");
    }
}
catch (final IOException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Following Java Code Conventions, "Open brace “{” appears at the end of the same line as the declaration statement".